# Return string if data is empty, nil or blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `text_area` that I want to set the `placeholder` attribute for if a particular object is empty, nil or blank.

I'm currently doing this:

```
<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: @response.followup ||= "Would you like to add a note?" %>
```

And that seems to work if `@response.followup` is `nil`, but if it's just empty...it doesn't use the `"Would you like to add a note?"` default text I'm setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check if you have `presence` available in your rails version. If it is, you can do the following

```
<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: @response.followup.presence || "Would you like to add a note?" %>
```

If it's not available, you can choose one of the following

1. use a decorator/presenter (i think this is overkill)
2. set the value of the placeholder in the controller

   `@response.followup = 'Would you like to add a note?' if response.blank?`
3. use a ternary operator in the view

   `<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: (@response.followup.blank? ? "Would you like to add a note?" : @response.followup) %>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test for "blankness" and use:

```
placeholder: !@response.followup.blank? ? @response.followup : "Would you like to add a note?"
```

So, if the followup isn't blank then use it, otherwise use your default text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: (@response.followup.blank? ? "Would you like to add a note?" : @response.followup) %>
```

or perhaps

```
<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: (@response.followup.present? ? @response.followup : "Would you like to add a note?") %>
```

if you find that reads better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [present?](http://railsless.blogspot.in/2011/08/difference-between-nil-empty-blank.html) method

```
<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: (@response.followup.present? ? "Would you like to add a note?" : @response.followup) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this so often, I had to make something like this:

```
class Object
  def fill(wtf)
    present? ? self : wtf
  end
end
```

`<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: @response.followup.fill("Would you like to add a note?") %>`

Example:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'

class Object
  def fill(wtf)
    present? ? self : wtf
  end
end

p nil.fill("omg")
```